# htaccess add .html extension for urls with or without trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So to begin with I have a custom url rewrite that sends a request variable to a php script

Rewrite rule is below:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

So if you access something like `domain.com/slug-text` it sends `slug-text` to `index.php` located in folder named test.

What I want is all my urls to look like `domain.com/slug-text.html`, but `slug-test` variable should still be sent to `index.php` file.

And

What I can't figure out is the redirect. I want all the old urls to be redirected from `domain.com/slug-text` or `domain.com/slug-text/` to `domain.com/slug-text.html` and `slug-text` sent to `index.php` file located in test folder.

Searched a lot but could not find the answer for this question anywhere on the Internet.

Thank you all for the help.

UPDATE:
my new code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([\w/\-]+)?[\w-])(?!:\.html)$ http://domain.com/$1\.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([\w/\-]+)?[\w-])(/|\.html)?$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

`domain.com/slug-text/` does not get redirected to `domain.com/slug-text.html`
`domain.com/slug-text` works as intended redirecting to `domain.com/slug-text.html`

What do i need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(([\w/\-]+)?[\w-])(/|\.html)?$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Will trap `domain.com/slug-text`, `domain.com/slug-text/` and `domain.com/slug-text.html` and send `slug-text` to `/test/index.php` inside `slug` param.

If you really want to redirect using `[R=301]` from old urls to new then use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])/?(?!:\.html)$ http://domain.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])\.html$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Also note that as using explicit redirect bottom rule is modified to trap url's ending with `.html`

It is also advisable (if your .htaccess does not already contain this) to filter conditions for existing files and folders not to be trapped by your redirect rules. Simply add these lines before `RewriteRule` lines:

```
# existing file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# existing folder
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```

And if using symlinks:

```
# enable symlinks
Options +FollowSymLinks
# existing symlink
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
```

// addition
Your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])/?(?!:\.html)$ http://domain.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])\.html$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: you need to add `http://` infront of `domain.com` or apache will prepend url with `/path/to/webserver/root` so your redirected url probably looks like `domain.com/var/www/domain.com/some-slug.html` which generated 404 Not Found

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` in your .htaccess? It must be before any `RewriteRule` or `RewriteCond`

Comment: pasted my whole htaccess in the update of the main question, thank you a lot for your help btw

Comment: the code in my htaccess is the same way you posted, everything works as intended jsut that urls with trailing slash at the end do not get redirected to .html which i want them to be

Comment: ahh, I get it now... it should be fixed now, my answer is updated

Comment: And, is it possible to make the http://domain.com dynamic? %{HTTP_HOST} didn't work for me...

Comment: @Jay do you mean that http://domain.com to be dynamically changed depending on rule. It can be **semi-dynamic**. you can create two or more `RewriteRule` each redirects to different domain. I think it can be (although I did not tested this yet) **fully-dynamic**, but I would not go further than making a subdomain dynamic: `RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?(?!:\.html)l$ http://$1.domain.com/$2.html [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to redirect /slug-text to /slug-text.html

```
RedirectMatch ^/([\w-]+)/?$ http://domein.com/$1.html
```

This is in the case when slug-text is only letters, digits, – and _.
Rewrite slug-text.html to a php file and pass the slug as a param:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [R,L]
```

If you have both line in your .htaccess the first one will do the redirects from the legacy URLs to the new ones and the second one will process the request.