# how to put .html at the end of url without effecting file type

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

my htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/detail\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^temp/detail/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^temp/detail/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

make my url like

```
temp.example.com/detail/xxxxxx
```

from

```
temp.example.com/detail.php?id=xxxxxx
```

now i want to append .html at the end, so that url become like:

```
temp.example.com/detail/xxxxxx.html
```

I need and htaccass rule, which will make my url like above, but shouldn't behave like html.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the extension at all? It's not SEO friendly.

Comment: same question i asked, but boss is always right you know :P

Comment: It's been asked several time on stackoverflow. [answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension) [answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682420/htaccess-add-html-extension-for-urls-with-or-without-trailing-slash). Then you just need to adjust the rules for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/detail\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ detail/%1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^detail/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)(?:\.html)?$ detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```