# Add .html extension to slug

Tags: .htaccess

On this post: [htaccess add .html extension for urls with or without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682420/htaccess-add-html-extension-for-urls-with-or-without-trailing-slash/18682657#18682657) I got 99% of the solution for re-writing slug to .html extension.
My question is, is it also possible to make
    `http://domain.com`
dynamic?

The index.php may or may not be running on a sub-directory (IE. test/index.php).

The code on the mentioned post is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])/?(?!:\.html)$ http://domain.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])\.html$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

PS: %{HTTP_HOST} doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This should work by removing host part from target URI:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])/?(?!:\.html)$ /$1.html [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])\.html$ admin/index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this and there are no other rules.